# Testing environment for utility class that reads / writes .properties file

Tags: java, io, properties-file

I'm working in a class that needs to read/write in a `.properties` file at runtime, based on some app's requirements.

The project's structure for this fragment of the app is as follows:

```
src
  |-main
  |    |-java
  |    |    |-file
  |    |         |-FileUtil.java
  |    |
  |    |-resources
  |              |-file.properties
  |
  |-test
       |-java
       |    |-file
       |         |-FileUtilTest.java
       |
       |-resources
                 |-file.properties
```

So the goal is that `FileUtilTest`instantiates a `FileUtil` object, call the corresponding `FileUtil` methods and make some assertions on `file.properties`. I've successfully read from `file.properties` but I'm not quite sure if it'll read/write correctly to `src/main/resources/file.properties` instead of to `src/test/resources/file.properties`.

How can I say for sure if the tested methods will read/write the proper file in production environment?

If you need any extra info about my class just let me know. Thanks in advance for your answers.

## Edit #1

This is the code I have so far:

#### `FileUtil.java`

```
public class FileUtil {

    // File name
    static final String DATA_FILE = "file.properties";

    // Property names
    static final String CURRENT_YEAR_PROPERTY = "currentYear";
    static final String CURRENT_NUMBER_PROPERTY = "currentNumber";

    int currentYear;
    String currentNumber;
    private File file;
    private Properties properties;

    public FileUtil() {
        try {
            loadDataFile();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getNextNumber() {
        Integer nextInteger;
        String result = null;

        if (currentNumber != null) {
            nextInteger = Integer.parseInt(currentNumber) + 1;
            result = String.format("%08d", nextInteger);
            properties.setProperty("currentNumber", result);
        }

        return result;
    }

    // Utility method to load the current values in the class. IOE should never be thrown
    private void loadDataFile() throws IOException {
        properties = new Properties();

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        file = new File(classLoader.getResource(DATA_FILE).getFile());

        properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
        currentYear = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("currentYear"));
        currentNumber = properties.getProperty("currentNumber");
        properties.store(new FileOutputStream(file), null);
    }
}
```

#### `FileUtilTest.java`

```
public class FileUtilTest {

    private FileUtil fileUtil;
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FileUtilTest.class.getName());

    // Properties to “reset” the file in every test
    private final String INITIAL_CURRENT_YEAR = "2017";
    private final String INITIAL_CURRENT_NUMBER = "00004954";

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws FileNotFoundException {
        fileUtil = new FileUtil();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws IOException {
        fileUtil = null;
        Properties initialProperties = new Properties();
        initialProperties.put(FileUtil.CURRENT_YEAR_PROPERTY, INITIAL_CURRENT_YEAR);
        initialProperties.put(FileUtil.CURRENT_NUMBER_PROPERTY, INITIAL_CURRENT_NUMBER);

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(FileUtil.DATA_FILE).getFile());
        initialProperties.store(new FileOutputStream(file), null);
    }

    @Test
    public void dataFileReadCorrectly() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Current year = {0}", fileUtil.currentYear);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Current number = {0}", fileUtil.currentNumber);

        // Testing the loadDataFile() as it’s called in the constructor 
        assertEquals(2017, fileUtil.currentYear);
        assertEquals("00004954", fileUtil.currentNumber);
    }

    @Test
    public void nextNumberObtainedCorrectly() {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Next number = {0}", fileUtil.getNextNumber());

        // Testing the value obtained from getNextNumber()
        assertNotNull(fileUtil.getNextNumber());
        assertEquals("00004955", fileUtil.getNextNumber());
    }

}
```

#### `file.properties`

```
currentYear=2017
currentNumber=00004954
```

To summarize, the class reads the values from the properties file and calculates nextNumber with `getNextNumber()`. The user can call another method (not yet implemented) that writes the next number to the properties file so when the user needs another number he gets the next and so on. When the year changes `currentNumber` is set to `00000001` and `currentYear` is updated, do I made myself clear?

Hope that helps to clarify the question.

## Edit #2

I forgot to say: by the time I wrote this post, I didn't had the body of `setUp()` and `tearDown()`. Now the test are giving me a `NumberFormatException:` and a `ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String` (I'm trying to use `INITIAL_CURRENT_YEAR` as an `Integer` instead of `String`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost guaranteed that it won't be able to write to the properties file in production--the inside of a jar isn't writable.

It would be better to structure your API to operate on an `InputStream` or `Reader` (and write to `PrintStream` or `Writer`) and test on in-memory streams, then separate your file-open logic.

Comment: I'm not getting quite well your answer. I added more info, please check it and tell me if I'm using `InputStream` as you say

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza No. Split the "open the file" and "read/write the file contents" into separate methods. You *will not* be able to write back to the file once the library is packaged as a jar, and you should pass the appropriate I/O object in as a parameter instead of hard-coding it.

Comment: So you say I need a method `File openFile(String location)` wich reads using a `InputStream` object and other `void read/writeFile(File file)` that uses a `PrintStream`, am I correct? what's the difference between `PrintStream` and `OutputStream`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `Writer` instead of `OutputStream`

Comment: So, In conclusion, my approach is incorrect, I'm considering other options to replace the `.properties` file